# SwiftUI Table TableColumn header row customization?

Tags: swiftui, tablecolumn

I must be missing something, but is there no way to use Table/TableColumn and be able to specify the background color, and different foreground color/font for the header row?
New to SwiftUI and the only way I can see doing this is by using HStack or List and individually formatting labels for 1st row perhaps?

Comment: `Table` provides minimal formatting. To style it how you want, consider using a `Grid` instead… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482532/how-can-i-display-tabular-data-with-swiftui-on-iphone/75483438#75483438

Comment: I was pretty sure I am not missing this, but then sorting and other defaults of Table and TableColumn needs to be handled? Seems kind of limited...

Comment: Each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/openalloc/SwiftTabler which seems to be pretty good alternative with some tweaks looks pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quit easy. You use a Text field for the header.

TableColumn(Text("Column Name").foregroundStyle(.black).bold())